# How to modify a bibtex entry in APA 6 style?

Tags: bibliographies, babel, apa-style

I am a french Latex user and I am searching for a way to modify the following short sentence "retrieved from" into "récupéré de" in a bibtex file. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `biblatex` and the `apa` style, this will be done automatically.  All you need to do is tell it to use the correct localization file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@electronic{electronic,
    Author = {Domi},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-16 19:40:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-16 19:42:54 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {2016-06-16},
    Month = {06},
    Title = {How to modify a bibtex entry in {APA} 6 style?},
    Url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315035/2693},
    Urldate = {2016-06-16},
    Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{electronic}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't ask correctly my question. I'm going to ask a new question.