# Modifying a bibtex entry using apacite

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, babel, apa-style, apacite

I'm currently writing a long document in French and I use `apacite` in order to classify my references according to APA 6th. When I compile my bib file, I obtain the following sentence : "consulté sur" before the reference of a website address. I would like to change that sentence into : "récupéré de" (translation in French of "retrieved from"). Someone here told me that I could use `biblatex` ([How to modify a bibtex entry in APA 6 style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315035/2693)) How do I do this using `apacite` instead?

Comment: Please for your future questions, give enough information to show the problem you are having. For a bibliography question like this, a minimal example like the one in my answer would have made it much easier to solve your problem initially without having to ask two questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the `apacite` version of what you want to do. The localization strings are found in the `french.apc` file that is part of `apacite`. They must be changed at the beginning of the document, not in the preamble.

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@electronic{electronic,
    Author = {Domi},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-16 19:40:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-16 19:42:54 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {2016-06-16},
    Month = {06},
    Title = {How to modify a bibtex entry in {APA} 6 style?},
    Url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315035/2693},
    Urldate = {2016-06-16},
    Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Récupéré  le {#1}, de\ }%
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Récupéré de\ }%
}
\begin{document}
\cite{electronic}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]